# Disable Force Stop Button or Create a unstopable android service

Tags: android, service

I'm having the follow question how I'm disable Force Stop button, this is to accomplish one task of my project this is not for virus or malware or malicious things. I have to disable it for my service do not be killed because inside him it checks the time and create a file in a determinate time of system this is because my client wants to block the Android OS when it creates. I've already searched and appears if you start the with `startForeground()` method the force stop button became disable and another solution but i do not find much material is about create a system service if anyone know i will be happy. And if want make a suggestion for my work and works i will be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: You mean the one in system settings > apps? You can't. And creating a system service? You can't either unless you create your own device firmware.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  The user is always able to stop a service on the phone, as he should be-  its his phone, he can decide he doesn't want your app to run anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The force close button appears because your program has entered a state in which it can no longer be executed sensibly (for instance an uncaught exception). Disabling the display of the close button will not solve your problem, you should debug your code.

Comment: I think he meant force stop under the applications settings menu-  which allows you to kill an application entirely in any state.